# Calling a function per frame in Java - Minecraft Plugin -

Tags: frame-rate

I am not the best at Java but I am working on a plugin for a Minecraft server, I became a Dev but I am making a plugin where I enter a command it should open a GUI inventory/chest and there should be items cycling in the middle and it starts fast and then slows down and when it stops the sender should receive the item in the middle, so the only thing I need is how I can make a 9*3 inventory I can only make 9 slots :/ And then how I can make the items cycle in the middle, if I would be working in Unity I would just use loops and void Update() {} But Java is just so confusing, I now everything except calling per frame :( Please someone help :)

Thanks

Comment: so... basically a slot machine?

Comment: `"I would just use loops [...] But Java is just so confusing"` - Java has loops too.  Is there a particular platform or framework or API you're using to make this plugin?  Exactly what functionality is available to you?  Currently the question is a bit too broad.

Comment: I didn't know much about plugins but I was on a like i don't know how to explain this, but this was like, kinda like a lesson on python, and we were learning about loops and I figured that I could just use loops and then when it hits a certain number it can trigger another loop that will make it go slower and so on, until it stops and gives you the item. I think I can handle this now ;)

Comment: I mean that I didn't know much about loops not plugins lol